# why pymongo collection defenition rises the number of threads?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

When I define a pymongo collection this way, Number of threads will increase by 2:

```
import threading
print threading.activeCount()


def db_bigadevs():
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    con_bigadevs = MongoClient()
    return con_bigadevs['bigadevs']


class collections:
    print 'A1 %s' % threading.activeCount()
    col_webs = db_bigadevs()['webs']
    print 'A2 %s' % threading.activeCount()
```

Output is:

```
1
A1 1
A2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each MongoClient has a single background thread for periodic cleanup tasks, as well as a background thread per server for monitoring the status of your MongoDB servers. So if you create the default MongoClient it connects to one server on localhost:27017, spawning a total of two threads.

[A brief explanation is here, where the FAQ says "MongoClient spawns multiple threads to run background tasks such as monitoring connected servers."](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe) [I wrote a very thorough explanation of PyMongo's use of threads here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/developer/periodic_executor.html), intended mainly for future PyMongo maintainers.

Comment: Is it costly for program performance?
Is the a better way to avoid these threads?

Comment: It isn't costly, no. Each thread wakes only every few seconds, and costs a few kilobytes of memory.